# How to ensure that 2 couples of figures are on 2 facing pages?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, positioning

I would like to reproduce the following layout with two figures on one
page and two others on the facing pages.

[image]

I would like the first couple to be on an even-numbered page and the
second on an odd-numbered page so that all four figures can be seen
together when the manuscript is printed and bound.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `dpfloat` package for that:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{dpfloat}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Some Text

\begin{figure}
  \begin{leftfullpage}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3cm]{inserthere}
    \caption{LEFT 1}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3cm]{inserthere}
    \caption{LEFT 2}
  \end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{fullpage}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3cm]{inserthere}
    \caption{RIGHT 1}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3cm]{inserthere}
    \caption{RIGHT 2}
  \end{fullpage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is not working with the Koma script class `scrbook` ?
I got 200 messages like this 

`dpfloat moved a leftpage float from page 15.`
and then

`! Output loop---200 consecutive dead cycles.`

Comment: @AlfredM.I guess this is not connected to the KOMA script class. LaTeX is not able to put the two pages near where you want it and so it gave up and put the pages at the end (of the chapter?). It should work if you remove approximately one page of content before the two page float. I guess, you should leave it until the document is finished and try to fine tune the place of the floats then.

Comment: You guess right as the `book` class gives the same behaviour. I'll follow your advice and hope that my deadline is ahead when it will be time to ajust figures placement.

Comment: Class like `scrreprt` do not raise an error but the figures can be placed on odd--even pages instead of even--odd only.

Comment: @AlfredM.Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I guess it's working with ``scrreprt`` because the page order has changed so LaTeX can find a place for the two consecutive pages, which have to even and odd).

Comment: I meant that it does not work because they are put at page 15 and 16 which means that the figures would end up on the two faces of a sheet when printed.
Pages 14 and 15 or 16 and 17 would be ok.

Comment: To prevent errors like `Output loop---200 consecutive dead cycles`, you can increase the maximum dead cycles by inserting something like `\maxdeadcycles=1000` in the preamble.