# Force placement of pairs of figures on even and odd page

Tags: floats, double-sided

Is there a possibility to place pairs of figures on the even page and the corresponding odd page, respectively? The scenario is that I have e.g. 2 figures showing the same statistic (separating males and females). Each figure spreads over a whole page. Now, it would be very good for improved readability (for comparing males' and females' results) if this pair would be placed on corresponding even and odd pages:

```
|~~~~~~~~~~||~~~~~~~~~~|
|Text Lorem||elitr, sed|
|ipsum dolo||eirmod te |
|sit amet  ||fot.      |
|sed diam  ||          |
|ut et doro||          |
|~~~~~~~~~~||~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~||~~~~~~~~~~|
|-FigureA-+||-FigureA-+|
|-females+-||-males+-++|
|++++---+++||+++-+----+|
|-++-++--++||+++-+-----|
|++-++-++-+||--+-+--+-+|
|~~~~~~~~~~||~~~~~~~~~~|

\documentclass[twoside=on]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam  
et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,  
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{statisticA-females.pdf}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{statisticA-males.pdf}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Hence, what I need, is something like `\cleardoublepage` without leaving float mode for figures (without creating empty space, at least, as Long as there is text left).

Is this possible? Thanks for any suggestions!

Fabian

Comment: this may be of help: [How to ensure that 2 couples of figures are on 2 facing pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70558/579)

Comment: The `dpfloat`-package works absolutely fine, thanks a lot!